# How to prevent event when the property change in another event in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How to prevent event when the property change in another event in winform?
I'm making a custom button.
So I make auto text align and I write text align method.

```
 private void ResetTextAlignment()
 {
     if(textAlignment != SB_TextAlignmentType.None)
     {
         Size curTextSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, TextFont);

         if (curTextSize.Height > Size.Height)
             textPos.Y = 0;
         else
             textPos.Y = (Size.Height - curTextSize.Height) / 2.0f;

         switch (textAlignment)
         {
             case TextAlignmentType.Left:
                 textPos.X = 0;
                 break;
             case TextAlignmentType.Right:
                 textPos.X = Size.Width - curTextSize.Width;
                 break;
             case TextAlignmentType.Center:
                 if (curTextSize.Width > Size.Width)
                     textPos.X = 0;
                 else
                     textPos.X = (Size.Width - curTextSize.Width) / 2.0f;
                 break;
         }               
     }
     DesignRefresh();
 }
```

This method will reset the text position , but I want to call this method in 
the control's size changed, font changed ... etc events callback method. But this method change property so this method invoke another event method.

So i must prevent events when I change the property in this method.
How should i gonna do?

Comment: Could you have a field in the class called `inProgress` and check if it is `true` at the start of your method? Then your method `return` if it is `true` and otherwise it sets it to `true` at the start of the method and `false` at the end (ensuring it only runs once at a time)?

Comment: Try calling [`Control.SuspendLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) (along with the associated `Control.ResumeLayout`).